# Java Memory Leak or not?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

It appears my project is not properly clearing some objects after they are supposed to be cleared.  I'm trying to find out where the problem is, and am wondering if the following represents a memory leak.
Let's say class Parent stores an object of type Child.  Later on, the Child object initializes a variable of class Thing.  Class Thing contains a reference to the Child.  If the Parent then calls clear() to set the Child to null, will the reference to Child within the class Thing still be kept?

```
public class Parent {
    private Child ex = new Child();

    public void clear() {
        ex = null;
    }

}

public class Child {

    private Thing thing;

    public Child() {
        thing = new Thing(this);
    }

}

public class Thing {

    private Child ex;

    public Thing(Child e) {
        ex = e;
    }

}
```

Comment: Reference "cycles" do not cause a problem for Java GC.  Only if there is a definite path from some "root" (stack var, static var, etc) to an object is the object kept and not collected.

Comment: In what you described there is **no** memory leak. Most likely it's impossible to create memory leak with the logic like yours.

Comment: In standard Java there is essentially no such thing as a "leak".  The main hazard is rather than you accidentally keep addressability to an object because, say, some ArrayList of objects is logically "abandoned" but left referenced and accessible.

Comment: Why would you believe that setting a Parent's (or any object's) member variable to any value would have an effect on the value of member variables of other objects...? That doesn't happen, and this isn't a special case. As for object cleanup, if there are no more *accessible* references, then the GC will *eventually* take care of the object at some unknown and uncontrollable point in the future.

Comment: One thing to remember is that the GC won't run until it feels like it; garbage is rarely collected immediately.

Comment: @JasonC Not even _"eventually"._ It is not guaranteed that GC will ever happen.

Comment: I still don't understand why the OP thinks there is a leak. The misunderstanding will almost surely fall out from that. @Rahul

Comment: @SeanOwen See [Memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak): _" In object-oriented programming, a memory leak may happen when an object is stored in memory but cannot be accessed by the running code."_ Why are there (two) remaining objects? (at least in theory) → see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26559012/1744774).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not answerable based on the information presented, because it all depends if there are any other current references to the Child object. Just because Parent nulls a *variable* doesn't mean that an object that the variable previously referenced loses all of its references. If on the other hand you are sure that there are no other active references to the Child object (or its constituents), then the Child object is available for GC'ing.

---

**Edit**
You ask,

> I'm wondering if a class variable within Child, containing a reference to Child, will hold the reference after the Parent class sets its Child to null. No other references in this example.

Yes the thing variable will still reference the Thing object created, but if there are no other references to that Thing, it all would be available for GC'ing if Child loses all references since neither the Child object, nor its Thing component would be reachable by any *live thread* or static references.

Comment: I'm wondering if a class variable within Child, containing a reference to Child, will hold the reference after the Parent class sets its Child to null.  No other references in this example.

Comment: I'm sorry, but -1 unless: Could you please clarify for me how you come to "_live thread_ or static references". Have you seen [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26559012/1744774)?

Answer (score 3):

One could add the following code to make it more clear (and working):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Parent().clear();
}
```

So, there are two objects that *remain* referenced (at least in theory):

- a `Thing` object via `Child.thing`
- a `Child` object via `Thing.ex`

Since a picture's worth a thousand words (and because I really love ASCII art):

Situation before `parent.clear()`

```
parent
 -ex  ----> child <----------------+
             -thing  ----> thing   |
                            -ex  --+
```

Situation after `parent.clear()`

```
parent
 -ex        child <----------------+
             -thing  ----> thing   |
                            -ex  --+

           Two remaining objects on the 
           heap referencing each other.
```

The references remain just on the heap, of course, but there is nothing in the [The Java® Language Specification, Java SE 8 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) about *"live thread"*, *"static reference"*, *"accessible"* or *"a definite path from some 'root' (stack var, static var, etc)"* in conjunction with garbage collection. That's what I found searching for "garbage":

(1) [Ch. 1. Introduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-1.html) – *"The Java programming language [...] includes automatic storage management, typically using a garbage collector,"*

*Typically* is not *necessarily.*

(2) [1.1. Organization of the Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.1) – *"When an object is no longer referenced, it may be reclaimed by the garbage
collector."*

*May be* is not *will be.*

As [Jason C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616460/jason-c) pointed out there's also something about GC in [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/):

(3) [2.5.3. Heap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3) – *"Heap storage for objects is reclaimed by an automatic storage management system (known as a garbage collector);"*

(4) [2.5.4: Method Area](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3) – *"Although the method area is logically part of the heap, simple implementations may choose not to [...] garbage collect [...] it."*

**Conclusion: A GC may be (and most likely is) implemented to recognize references that exist between objects on the heap only, in order to remove the associated objects. But that's not a matter of the JLS or JVM spec. It is implementation-specific and, hence, cannot be answered universally.**

---

Additional info:

There is the term *"accessible" in: "6.6 Access Control – If access is permitted, then the accessed
entity is said to be accessible."* → But the section is about AC, not about GC.

The proper term for referenced objects is *reachable*, and *"live thread"* is also there: *"12.6.1 Implementing Finalization – A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread."* → But the section is about finalization, not about GC.

Comment: I can appreciate the careful reference to the JLS here but you seem to suggest that the likely answer is that the JVM has no garbage collector. This is not true for any JVM in existence even if the Java language never requires it per se.

Comment: @SeanOwen That's not what I meant or said. It's the conclusion in the last paragraph before the separator line. In other words: It cannot be said what a specific JVM's GC implementation does without looking at its spec.  With just the given code, not mentioning any specific JVM in the OP's question the JLS is the (only) point of reference. Considering this...see above.

Comment: Yes, not enough info, but I find it overwhelming likely that a) there's another reference to the 'recoverable' objects, or b) GC exists but just hasn't run. I completely understand the issue, I just don't think this directly addresses the likely far simpler practical question here.

Comment: @SeanOwen How do you know [which of these JVM implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) the OP uses? How do you know how the implementation he uses works in detail? Without knowing this everything is just guessing or assuming (or taking something well-known and wide-spread and generalizing from this). I on the other hand decided to be precise when it comes to programming questions long ago. The most precise answers that can be given under the given circumstances, the given question, the given code are from the JLS. Period.

Comment: I like precision, and the detail is always good to read. For this question, it's my opinion that this kind of response is like answering "yes" to "do you know what time it is?"

Comment: @SeanOwen _"I find it overwhelming likely that a) there's another reference to the 'recoverable' objects,"_ – This is just guessing / assuming, too. Your personal interpretation, not representing the question's content. I can imagine just one additional class `Test` containing: `public static void main(String[] args) { new Parent().clear(); }`. That's all it needs.

Comment: @SeanOwen _"this kind of response is like ..."_ – This is your interpretation, too. ;-

Comment: if the point of this answer isn't "you technically can't rely on any GC" then I am not sure what it is. Your words seem to suggest the best answer is: it's because your JVM is unable to GC this circular reference. But there is no JVM that is unable to GC this (else: which one are you thinking of?) This is why I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: @GeriBroser Your deductions are correct, just adding an FYI: The JLS is not the document to search through for this. The [JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/) is what you want. All JVMs must adhere to this. Chapter 2, in particular 2.5.3 and 2.5.4, explicitly state what you deduced from the JLS (that it is all implementation-defined). It is a clearer source for information on subjects like this. That said, while it *is* implementation-defined, all common JVMs do have a similar typical behavior in actual practice.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, 2.5.3 reads _"is reclaimed by...a garbage collector"_. But also _"[JVM] assumes no particular type...may be chosen according to the implementor"_. Isn't that what I always said: it depends on the implementation. Is it _"simple implementations may choose not to...garbage collect"_ you're referring to in 2.5.4? However, top of chapter 2 reads _"This document specifies an abstract machine. It does not describe any particular implementation of the JVM."_ Maybe that's what it's all about: Some were thinking _concrete._ I was thinking _abstract._ :-)

Comment: @GeriBroser Yes, those are the portions I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is an object cycle that's disconnected with the rest of the object graph.

Java's garbage collectors work by traversing all the objects that can be reached from a small set of root objects, and disposing the rest of the objects. In fact, it doesn't care that much about the things it didn't reach, it could be unreferenced objects or just random uninitialized memory - I think that's one of the factors why there are no destructors in Java.

That problem you mention would occur in languages which use reference count for memory management, like Objective-C has/had (it may have changed *kind of recently*, I can't recall). As both objects are being referenced by the other, none of them is elegible for being `free`d.

You can see some extra explanation (and some charming animations - yay!) in the article [Visualising Garbage Collection Algorithms](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/09/03/visualizing-garbage-collection-algorithms/), by Ken Fox.

Comment: JVM implementations could, technically, use reference-counted memory management and still adhere to the JVM spec. In practice though, the widely-used ones behave as you describe.